# Which kind of HTML elements can be posted within a form?

Tags: html, forms, post

What are the HTML elements that support submitting values to server?

If it is all input tags, then `<select></select>` would be an exception. I couldn't find anything in common in elements that support the submission of key - value pairs (name - value) in a form submit.

```
<input type="text" value="123" name="fname"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="123" name="fname"/>
<select></select>
```

I want to know about elements like above that would submits it data to server on post. For example, `<div>` is an element that won't support this.

Comment: How is it an exception? And what are you trying to conclude?

Comment: I typed `<select>` there but not displayed since its an html. @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan

Comment: what exactly are you looking for my friend ?

Comment: What is not displayed? And where?

Comment: @GalV I want to know all of the elements that would submit its name and value to server on a form submit like text inputs do.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Corrected now

Comment: You are forgetting `<textarea>`s

Comment: Is [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms#HTML_Elements) what you're looking for?

Comment: @billyonecan Exactly, I searched but couldn't find it

Comment: @billyonecan If you please, then post it as an answer. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything that is inside a `form` will be submitted. Inputs are the basic, textarea and some others are sent as well (`select`).

You mentioned that `select` is not sent to server.

Have you tried to give it a name?

Use this:

```
<select name="somename">
  <option value="1">Hello!</option>
</select>
```

This will send the value of `1` for the name `somename`. You can try your own. When you give an input a name, you can access its value from the server, if you are using `GET` request method, then you will see the name in the URL of the select followed by a `=` and the value for that.

```
<input type="text" value="123" name="fname"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="123" name="fname"/>
<select></select>
```

Correct! You can see for yourself, you are giving a name to the input, but no name for the select. Edit it, and give it a name! Then you will get it on the serverside for processing. :)

Try this:

```
<input type="text" value="123" name="fname"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="123" name="fname"/>
<select name="select">
 <option value="1">Hello Subin!</option>
</select>
```

Note that, the text inside the option tags is just for the user to see, the value sent to server is an attribute for the option tag.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms

Comment: in case, `textarea` should also be an exception :D Doesn't it? hehehe so, everything that has a value will be sent to the server..

Comment: :-) No such general rules I think. Mozilla documentation is the only thing I suppose https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms

Comment: Well, if to be sure the main thing that is sent is known as HttpHeaders which contains everything, Browser name, OS name, Form Data, XMLHttpRequest and all that..that is which is sent to the server, only input and select doesn't count! Even your browser detail is sent..

Comment: From html I'm asking. If the post is made from a form submission. Sorry, I couldn't make my question clear, thats why 3 downvotes and 3 close votes there